# How execute a mapreduce programs in oozie with hadoop-2.2

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, oozie

2.2.0 and oozie-4.0.0 in ubuntu. I am cant able to execute mapreduce programs in oozie.

i am uisng resource manager port number for jobtracker 8032 in oozie.

while scheduling in oozie to goes to running state and running in yarn also  after some time i am getting error like this(below) in hadoop logs and still running in oozie logs

Error:

```
2014-05-30 10:38:14,322 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerRequestor: getResources() for application_1401425739447_0003: ask=3 release= 0 newContainers=0 finishedContainers=0 resourcelimit=<memory:1024, vCores:-1> knownNMs=1
2014-05-30 10:38:17,296 INFO [Socket Reader #1 for port 47412] SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for job_1401425739447_0003 (auth:SIMPLE)
2014-05-30 10:38:17,316 INFO [IPC Server handler 0 on 47412] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: JVM with ID : jvm_1401425739447_0003_m_000002 asked for a task
2014-05-30 10:38:17,316 INFO [IPC Server handler 0 on 47412] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: JVM with ID: jvm_1401425739447_0003_m_000002 given task: attempt_1401425739447_0003_m_000000_0
2014-05-30 10:38:22,524 INFO [IPC Server handler 1 on 47412] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1401425739447_0003_m_000000_0
2014-05-30 10:38:25,996 INFO [IPC Server handler 2 on 47412] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Status update from attempt_1401425739447_0003_m_000000_0
2014-05-30 10:38:26,003 INFO [IPC Server handler 2 on 47412] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1401425739447_0003_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2014-05-30 10:38:29,066 INFO [IPC Server handler 3 on 47412] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1401425739447_0003_m_000000_0
2014-05-30 10:38:32,071 INFO [IPC Server handler 4 on 47412] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1401425739447_0003_m_000000_0
2014-05-30 10:38:35,075 INFO [IPC Server handler 5 on 47412] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1401425739447_0003_m_000000_0
2014-05-30 10:38:38,079 INFO [IPC Server handler 6 on 47412] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Ping from attempt_1401425739447_0003_m_000000_0
this error continues...
```

i can able to run java example(give in oozie) mapreduce program in oozie.

if i am trying to run the pig,hive,sqoop or my own java mapreduce program i am getting the above error i dont know why it comes. i already given my hadoop configuration path in oozie and i started my jobhistory server.

Help me please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeManager and Resource Manager running in same system. So i am gettting this error. I started Node manager in second system and my problem is solved.

Comment: how to change node manager in different machine? please, help.

Comment: Hi, if u have a multinode cluster, means start the nodemanager, datanode in one system and namenode,resourcemanager,historyserver in another machine.

Comment: but, I am applying start-all.sh on master node and it will start all service on all nodes. It starts nodemanager,datanode on all nodes and resource manager on master node. what command I should use to run like you have mantioned?

Comment: Commands to start services use the following commands, nodemanager - "yarn nodemanager" , resourcemanager - "yarn resourcemanager" , namenode - "hadoop namenode" , datanode - "hadoop datanode" jobhistoryserver - "mapred historyserver" note : navigate to bin folder and execute the commands

Comment: that means Its not required to have 2 master nodes. I have to go to each node and open which ever service I want one-by-one, is it so?

Comment: yes correct, start namenode,resourcemanager, historyserver in master and datanode, nodemanager in slave