# Error while reading avro data file in oozie workflow - class is incompatible with new map API mode

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie, workflow-activity

I am trying to run a MR job from oozie workflow with avro data file as an input and output as well. Mapper emits Text and IntWritable. I am using a new mr api - mapreduce. My workflow definition is following:

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5" name="map-reduce-wf">
<global>
   <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
   <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
   <configuration>
        <property>
            <name>mapreduce.job.queuename</name>
            <value>${queueName}</value>
        </property>
    </configuration>
</global>

    <start to="mr-node"/>

    <action name="mr-node">
        <map-reduce>
            <prepare>
                <delete path="${nameNode}/${outputDir}"/>
            </prepare>
            <configuration>
                <!-- BEGIN: SNIPPET TO ADD IN ORDER TO MAKE USE OF NEW HADOOP API -->
                <property>
                  <name>mapred.reducer.new-api</name>
                  <value>true</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                  <name>mapred.mapper.new-api</name>
                  <value>true</value>
                </property>
                <!-- END: SNIPPET -->
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.map.class</name>
                    <value>com.ncr.bigdata.mr.avro.AvroPifDriver$PifMapper</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.reduce.class</name>
                    <value>com.ncr.bigdata.mr.avro.AvroPifDriver$PifReducer</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.map.tasks</name>
                    <value>1</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                    <value>${nameNode}/${inputDir}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                    <value>${nameNode}/${outputDir}</value>
                </property>                 
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.input.format.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>avro.schema.input.key</name>
                    <value>{"type":"record","name":"SampleRecord","namespace":"org.co.sample.etl.domain","fields":[{"name":"requiredName","type":"string"},{"name":"optionalName","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"dataItemLong","type":"long"},{"name":"dataItemInt","type":"int"},{"name":"startTime","type":"long"},{"name":"endTime","type":"long"}]}</value>
                </property>


                <property>
                    <name>mapred.output.format.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyValueOutputFormat</value>
                </property> 
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.output.key.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey</value>
                </property>   
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.output.value.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroValue</value>
                </property> 

                <property>
                    <name>avro.schema.output.key</name>
                    <value>string</value>
                </property> 
                <property>
                    <name>avro.schema.output.value</name>
                    <value>int</value>
                </property> 

            </configuration>
        </map-reduce>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Map/Reduce failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

My mapper looks following:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

 public static class PifMapper extends Mapper<AvroKey<PosData>, NullWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

        @Override
        public void map(AvroKey<PosData> key, NullWritable value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ...
        }
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
140807041959771-oozie-oozi-W@mr-node] Launcher exception: mapred.input.format.class is incompatible with new map API mode.
java.io.IOException: mapred.input.format.class is incompatible with new map API mode.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.ensureNotSet(Job.java:1172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.setUseNewAPI(Job.java:1198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
...
```

I am using Hadoop 2.2.0 (HDP 2.0), Oozie 4.0.0, Avro 1.7.4

Map reduce jobs submitted via driver class works fine. org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat should be implementation of the new mapreduce as well.

To make sure that there is no lib clash I removed shared lib from ozzie and all libs are included to workflow lib dir.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All is just a matter of finding correct properties for job configuration. Outdated documentation were a bit misleading. Following worked for us:

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5" name="map-reduce-wf">
<global>
   <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
   <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
   <configuration>
        <property>
            <name>mapreduce.job.queuename</name>
            <value>${queueName}</value>
        </property>
    </configuration>
</global>

    <start to="mr-node"/>

    <action name="mr-node">
        <map-reduce>
            <prepare>
                <delete path="${nameNode}/${outputDir}"/>
            </prepare>
            <configuration>
                <!-- BEGIN: SNIPPET TO ADD IN ORDER TO MAKE USE OF NEW HADOOP API -->
                <property>
                  <name>mapred.reducer.new-api</name>
                  <value>true</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                  <name>mapred.mapper.new-api</name>
                  <value>true</value>
                </property>
                <!-- END: SNIPPET -->
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.job.map.class</name>
                    <value>com.ncr.bigdata.mr.avro.AvroPifDriver$PifMapper</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.job.reduce.class</name>
                    <value>com.ncr.bigdata.mr.avro.AvroPifDriver$PifReducer</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.map.tasks</name>
                    <value>1</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir</name>
                    <value>${nameNode}/${inputDir}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir</name>
                    <value>${nameNode}/${outputDir}</value>
                </property>                 
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.job.inputformat.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat</value>
                </property>

                <property>
                    <name>avro.schema.input.key</name>
                    <value>{"type":"record","name":"SampleRecord","namespace":"org.co.sample.etl.domain","fields":[{"name":"requiredName","type":"string"},{"name":"optionalName","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"dataItemLong","type":"long"},{"name":"dataItemInt","type":"int"},{"name":"startTime","type":"long"},{"name":"endTime","type":"long"}]}</value>
                </property>


                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.job.outputformat.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyValueOutputFormat</value>
                </property> 



                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.map.output.key.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.Text</value>
                </property>   
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.map.output.value.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable</value>
                </property> 


                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.job.output.key.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey</value>
                </property>   
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.job.output.value.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroValue</value>
                </property> 

                <property>
                    <name>avro.schema.output.key</name>
                    <value>"string"</value>
                </property> 
                <property>
                    <name>avro.schema.output.value</name>
                    <value>"int"</value>
                </property> 

            </configuration>
        </map-reduce>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Map/Reduce failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you: [how to execute mapreduce programs in oozie with hadoop 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948319/how-execute-a-mapreduce-programs-in-oozie-with-hadoop-2-2/24063008#24063008)